# how to make visual force email template render as word document?

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

i need this page as word document,`content type="application/word"` is not supporting here.this is my code

```
<messaging:emailTemplate subject="Test Email"  relatedToType="Invention_Disclosure_New__c">
<messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF" filename="{!relatedTo.Title__c}_Invention Disclosure questionaire.pdf">
<html>
    <head/>
    <body>
        <div>What is the invention? What are features of the invention and how do they solve the problem? Describe your implementation(s) of the invention using examples. (Tip: describe your invention as thoroughly as possible so that the reader can use this description to build the system that solves the problem.)
        </div>
            <div>{!relatedTo.Detailed_Description__c}</div>

    </body>
</html>
</messaging:attachment>
```

Comment: if the below answer was helpful, remember to mark it as accepted, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_messaging_attachment.htm the renderAs works with any valid mime type/sub-type https://www.freeformatter.com/mime-types-list.html

<s>so theoreticxally, changing the renderAs to: **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document** should cause it to attach as a .docx file.</s> While you may not get an error if you try to use this mime type; a .docx file is virtually a zip file and you can't define all the necessary components so you will always get an error when trying to open it.

```
<messaging:attachment renderAs="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" filename="{!relatedTo.Title__c}_Invention Disclosure questionaire.pdf">
```

You can use **application/msword** for the older generic word .doc format

Make sure your filename ends with the correct extension as well. So change the render as and then change the filename to use **.doc** Instead of **.pdf**.

Comment: i have used like this,<messaging:attachment renderAs="application/msword" filename="{!relatedTo.Title__c}_Invention Disclosure questionaire.docx"> downloading as word doc but content not opening,saying problem on opening content

Comment: That's because, as I said in my answer, that application/msword is .doc, NOT .docx. The .docx file is the really long one I posted. That being said, I just finished testing and you don't want to use .docx cause you'll always get that error (.docx is basically a zip of multiple files, there's not really a way to build that out in an email template like this). So, change your file extension to .doc and you'll be fine (I just tested and had no issues)

Comment: thanks,its working fine.<messaging:attachment renderAs="application/msword" filename="{!relatedTo.Title__c}_Invention Disclosure questionaire.doc">

Comment: If its working please remember to mark this as the acceptable answer to help future users who have the same question